# how to update 2 dataframe data with same columns on df.to_sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I have 2 datasets: old_data and new_data
Explanation: The columns of old_data and new_data are the same but I want to update the rows of old_data with new_data , can you help me?

`

```
old_data =pd.DataFrame(
{"Timestamp":['2022-11-01 22:00:11','2022-11-01 22:00:11','2022-11-01 22:00:11'],
   "Symbols":['Binance','OKX','Kucoin'],
    'USDT':[1235245657,5456245456,5454545649],
    'USDC':[455116511,65465464,465456456]
})
```

`

`

```
new_data = pd.DataFrame({"Timestamp":['2022-11-02 23:00:11','2022-11-02 23:00:11','2022-11-02 23:00:11'],"Symbols":['Binance','OKX','Kucoin'],'USDT':[125424245,54565456,5444127649],'USDC':[6545665,165654,165456]
})
```

`

The table in my database is old_data, now I want to update the rows of old_data with new_data

`from sqlalchemy import create_engine engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://xx:xxxx@localhost/stablecoin_db') new_data.to_sql('table',engine,if_exist='append')`

but not working for me, can you update help me 2 pandas with the same columns

Comment: Try:  if_exist='replace'

Comment: thank you But I don't want to delete all to update the new one, just want more updates